# How to use prepared statement that returns resultset with jdbcTemplate in spring mvc 3?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

Here is my code which uses jdbcTemplate

```
 String SQL = "select branch from branchTable where branch_name = '" + branch + "'";         
           ArrayList<String> branchList = (ArrayList<String>) jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new RowMapper() {
                  public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
                    return resultSet.getString("city_desc");
                  }
                });
                       return branchList;
```

Now i want to be able to use preparedstatement with a query like `"select branch from branchTable where branch_name = ?"`

How can i do that with jdbcTemplate ?
Examples i searched show demonstration on how to use it with update or insert query, but not with select query..

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JdbcTemplate has [another query() method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper%29) which takes arguments of the prepared statement as parameter:

```
jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, new Object[] {branchName}, new RowMapper() {...});
```

Note that:

- `SQL` should be named `sql`
- You should use `List` and not `ArrayList`. Nothing in the javadoc guarantees that an ArrayList is returned. And you shouldn't care about the concrete type of list returned.
- You should use a `RowMapper<String>` and not a raw `RowMapper`.